# dynamic input rows in a GridView when EDITing

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**Update:**

let say i have 4 `address` in my database and when i am displaying my address in the gridview which is readonly i have no problem. but how would you edit all 4 address? (this is just an examplei might have 4 or 3 or 2 or 10 address) when end user click on "`EDIT`" the row?

**Update end**

i have a gridview control with 3 columns `(id, name, address)` and the `address column` may have one or more `address` so when the user `click on Edit` how would i make that column editable? since the `address column` might have one or more address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the TextBoxes on the RowCreated event and use .Controls[rowId] to access them:

```
TextBox _token = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Controls[rowId] as TextBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

The GridView allows editing on a **row-by-row** basis. An editable GridView contains an additional column with an Edit button in each row. When the end user clicks on an Edit button that row becomes editable, causing the Edit button to change to Update and Cancel buttons and the other columns to become TextBoxes. The end user can then update one or more column values and click Update to save their changes.

Here is the [step by step tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)

And also make sure, id & Name columns ReadOnly property set to true.

```
 <asp:BoundField  ReadOnly="true" ...../>
```

Comment: Are you displaying all addres in the same column? If so use the OnRowUpdated event (is raised after the grid updates the row.) In that event get the multiple address field values and update DB accordingly

Comment: you are missing the main point, when you click on edit you will display address in a textbox right? and if so how will you generate textbox on fly? do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridView to display the addresses in the row, instead of a BoundField or however you are doing it.  When you click "Edit", put the GridView control in the selected row into an Edit state.

Comment: you mean master/detail grid?....well still my question is not address, my main concern is when you edit the row (as i have said i might have address 1 or 4 or 10) i should be able to edit the address in a textbox and able to update... let me know if you have done something similar -